# Insert row in table B on table A's insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Using MySQL, I assumed there was a way to do it relationally but perhaps I'm wrong.

I have table A with userID, and table B with userID, it's set so on delete of A.userID to cascade and delete B.userID.

So I have a query (Using CI), inserting information in table A, I want to insert a row into table B with the same userID (PK, AI). Sometimes it will have values to insert in B.userID row, sometimes it will be entirely null values.

Thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really need to see the actual query, but I believe this is what you're looking for.

When you insert data in CodeIgniter you can get the Primary Key of your insert like this.

```
$this->db->insert('A',$data);  //insert into the table with 'userID' as PK, AI

$id_of_insert = $this->db->insert_id();

$data_for_b = array(
    'field' => 'value',
    ...
    'userID' => $id_of_insert   //insert the captured PK from A and place in the FK field of B
);

$this->db->insert('B', $data_for_b);
```

Comment: Thanks, works a charm. Wish I knew of the insert_id function!

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/ is your friend. no sarcasm intended, sorry if you already knew about this one.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to write a stored procedure to perform the insert. That could do both inserts within a transaction and accept parameters for the data to add into B as well as A. Then you query would call the stored proc instead of doing a straight insert.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should consider in this approach:

1. If your auto_increment is BIGINT it gives wrong values.
2. If you insert something and someone else inserted something as well before you read the value you might get the wrong id. I recommend reading the value with something different that is unique. (e.g. nickname in a user registration).